# Association of financial phenomena/indications with the conservation laws of Black Scholes equation

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, econo-physics

For a while I've been doing research on methods of obtaining conservation laws via the symmetries of differential equations (DEs). I'm presently doing research on identifying financial indicators/phenomena that can be associated with the conservation laws of the [Black Scholes problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model).

I've done some reading on econophysics and quantitative finance but there seems to be lots of contrasting and confusing views on this matter.

Any contribution to shed light on this matter will be appreciated.

Comment: More on  Black & Scholes: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Black+Scholes